# How to map my data into the right format with RxJS

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reactive-programming, rxjs

## 1. What's going on

I have some data that I need to map into the right format to be useful for
what I want to do. The data I get can also vary in length (means, it could be
one object, or 10, or 200). However – I only ever care about the first 6
elements within that array. When there are only e.g. 3 elements, then I
still want to emit the result. But I do NOT want to emit a change when
the values didn't change (the source could trigger an update, but the data
could still be the same).

The data I may get looks like this:

```
var data = {
  myData: {
    cats: [             // data I care about!
      {
        name: 'Mr. Cat',
        someReallyLongPropertyNameThatLinksToAnImage: 'http://cat/ur/day.jpg',
        ... // SOME MORE PROPS
      },
      {
        name: 'Supercat',
        someReallyLongPropertyNameThatLinksToAnImage: 'http://cat/ur/day2.jpg',
        ... // SOME MORE PROPS
      },
      ... etc.
    ]  
  },
  foo: {                // data I don't care about...
    bar: [{...}...]     // data I don't care about...
  },
  baz: {
    butz: [{...}...]    // data I don't care about...
  }
}
```

The result I want should look like this:

```
var result = [
  {
    image: 'http://url/to/1',
    title: 'title 1'
  },
  {
    image: 'http://url/to/2',
    title: 'title 2'
  },
  {
    image: 'http://url/to/3',
    title: 'title 3'
  }
]
```

## 2. What's the problem?

My problem is, that I don't know how to:

- emit a change with *n* items (don't emit PER item)

  It looks like `bufferWithCount(6)` is some sort of what I am looking for,
  but that  doesn't work when there are only 3 elements within that array!
- only emit a change when the resulting array is different

  when the result looks exactly the same as before, then don't trigger
  a change event.

## 3. What I did (but doesn't work obviously)

```
Rx.Observable.of(data)
  .map((e) => data.myStuff.cats)
  .map((arr) => {
    // this would emit a change for EACH element, right? ugh.
    return Rx.Observable.fromArray(arr)
      // only care about the first 6 elements? if it only
      // has 3, would this still work?
      .take(6)
      // pluck out the props I need. (maybe not neccessary, but anyway)
      .pluck('someReallyLongPropertyNameThatLinksToAnImage', 'name') 
      .map((el) => {
        // map the data into the right format
        return {
          title: el.name
          image: el.someReallyLongPropertyNameThatLinksToAnImage
        }
      })
  })
  .distinctUntilChanged() // yeah... this doesn't work either I guess..
  .subscribe(
    (result) => console.log(result)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is probably easiest to just use the `Array.prototype.slice` method instead of trying to hack a solution with Rx.

As for using `distinctUntilChanged` you will need to use a comparer function to tell it how to compare the two arrays I imagine:

```
Rx.Observable.just(data)
  //Arrays slice will only take up to six items from the array 
  .map((e) => e.myData.cats.slice(0, 6))
  //Only updates if the array values have changed
  .distinctUntilChanged(null, (cur, next) => /*Implement your array value comparison*/)
  //Converts the values into something we can work with
  .map((arr) => arr.map(el => { 
                         return {name : el.name, 
                                 image : el.someBlahBlah}; 
                })
  )
  //Receives a series of arrays only if the values have changed.
  .subscribe();
```

As to how you would do the array comparison that is another matter entirely and is really up to you but you can see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853974/2521865).

Essentially though, the simplest solution would be to iterate through the arrays and check if the fields in the objects differ here is slightly modified code from the link:

```
// attach the .equals method to Array's prototype to call it on any array
Array.prototype.equals = function (array) {
  // if the other array is a falsy value, return
  if (!array)
      return false;

  // compare lengths - can save a lot of time 
  if (this.length != array.length)
      return false;

  for (var i = 0, l=this.length; i < l; i++) {
      //Compare properties here, 
      //just make sure you are comparing value instances not references     
      if (this[i].name != array[i].name) { 
          // Warning - two different object instances will never be equal: {x:20} != {x:20}
          return false;   
      }           
  }       
  return true;
}
```